# How to determine the number of consumers in a consumer group in Spingboot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm using annotation @KafkaListner to listen to a specific topic. However suddenly I noticed that there is a big lagging for the consumers to receive the messages from the producers. Then I increased the number of partitions of the brokers and the issue is solved.

After some researches I realized that the number of consumers in a consumer group cannot exceed the number of partitions otherwise some of the consumers would be inactive.

So in Spring Boot, does each individual @KafkaListener is considered as a single consumer? If not, how can I find the exact number of consumers in a consumer group thus I'm able to properly configure the partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does each individual @KafkaListener is considered as a single consumer?

No, it's a consumer group which can have one (default) or more consumer threads (Containers). You can use the `concurrency` property to override the ContainerFactory default property.

As you figured out, the number of topic's partitions determines the level of parallelism. If the concurrency is greater than the number of partitions, the concurrency is adjusted down such that each Container gets one partition.

Comment: So let's say in a "customer-consumer-group", I have 2 @kafkaListener A and B. If A has a concurrency of 10 and B has a concurrency of 5. So from your description the number of consumers in this group is 10 + 5 = 15 correct? Thus I better configure the number of partitions > 15.

Comment: CG/KafkaListener id must be unique and concurrency applies to it. In your example, 10 partitions would be enough. Each consumer in KafkaListener A would get 1 partition. Each consumer in KafkaListener B would get 2 partitions.

Comment: Got it. So even Kafka listener A and listener B are under same consumer group but they have different id so they are considered as different sets of consumers?
Like the 10 consumers (concurrency 10) are the first sets and 5 consumers (concurrency 5) are the second sets. 

I thought they will be combined together because they are at the same consumer group.

Comment: The `id` property (if present) is used as the Kafka consumer `group.id` property. So if you want to have a single CG, always use the same `id` (in that case, you need 15 partitions).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate your kindly reply.